# Are there any other signal interrupts with roscpp besides the default ctrl+c sigint handler

Tags: roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a ROS server that uses TCP/IP to communicate data.  While the server is listening for connections, the program is in somewhat of a sleep mode and so I cannot use the ros::ok command to check if the process has been killed. Are there are any other signal interrupts that come with roscpp that can deal with this?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9680/are-there-any-other-signal-interrupts-with-roscpp-besides-the-default-ctrl+c-sigint-handler/) by [yeasir](https://answers.ros.org/users/405/yeasir/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2011-04-08

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-04-12**:
Can you explain your use case a little more fully as to why ros::ok() does not work in your use case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There can be only one handler for any given signal at a time.  ROS does install a handler for SIGINT.   It is not possible to catch and handle SIGKILL.

---

Originally posted by [Straszheim](https://answers.ros.org/users/44/straszheim/) with karma: 426 on 2011-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1